# Sql queries result combine using where clause on result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two query result and i need to combine bot of result with condition on result in sql.
below give queries.

```
 Select  T1.class_id,T1.cloth_id,T2.cloth_id,T2.Views,T2.Posted_Date
 from abc_branch as T1
 cross join
 master_branch as T2
 where T1.cloth_id = T2.cloth_id

 Select  T1.class_id,T1.branch_code,T2.branch_code,T2.Views,T2.Posted_Date
 from temp_id as T1
 cross join
 master_id as T2
 where T1.branch_code = T2.branch_code
```

I need to combine query get result, and in result need to output on condition

1. if class_id came from first query then it can't came from second query in result ouptut.

Comment: `cross join` is intended to multiply rows of both the tables. Your current query is effectively an `inner join` (because of `where` clause), but it is not so explicitly specified. So you can replace `cross join` with `join on <your where condition>` to make it explicit for future readers.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? If you combine them with a `union` for example, then what does it matter if they came from the first or second query? You need to provide some sample data with expected output.

Comment: combine means.  three columns should come  like output of one query below output of second query.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and expected result, I do not understand what you want

Comment: I need results in three columns class_id, cloth_id and Views.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a job for `union` to me

you can combine both result sets like this

```
Select  T1.class_id, T1.cloth_id, T2.cloth_id,T 2.Views, T2.Posted_Date
from abc_branch as T1
  join master_branch as T2 on T1.cloth_id = T2.cloth_id

union

Select  T1.class_id, T1.branch_code, T2.branch_code, T2.Views, T2.Posted_Date
from temp_id as T1
  join master_id as T2 on T1.branch_code = T2.branch_code
```

Now if you want the result of one of these query before the other, add a sort field.
For example

```
Select  T1.class_id, T1.cloth_id, T2.cloth_id, T2.Views, T2.Posted_Date, 0 as sort
from abc_branch as T1
  join master_branch as T2 on T1.cloth_id = T2.cloth_id

union

Select  T1.class_id, T1.branch_code, T2.branch_code, T2.Views, T2.Posted_Date, 1 as sort
from temp_id as T1
  join master_id as T2 on T1.branch_code = T2.branch_code

order by sort
```

**The `sort` column can also be used in the resultset to know if the row came from the first or the second query.**

There are many ways of combining 2 queries, if this is not what you are looking for then update your question with more details about what you need

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  In this case, I would suggest `union all`:

```
select b.class_id, b.cloth_id, mb.cloth_id, mb.Views, mb.Posted_Date
from abc_branch b join
     master_branch mb
     on b.cloth_id = mb.cloth_id
union all
select t.class_id, t.branch_code, t.branch_code, m.Views, m.Posted_Date
from temp_id t join
     master_id m
     on t.branch_code = m.branch_code;
```

Notes:

- `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  Use that if you intend to remove duplicates; otherwise use `union all`.
- Use table aliases that are *meaningful* -- such as abbreviations for the table names.
- Both `union` and `union all` require that the columns have the same types for corresponding columns (positionally).